# How to display sold out message once an itemruns out of stock with PayPal smart button

Tags: php, paypal, payment-gateway

I am currently working on the store for my website. I am using the PayPal Smart button for payments. I was wondering how I can add a stock amount so that when stock number is 0, the ability to purchase becomes unavailable. I've searched everywhere around the internet and could not find  any answers for my question. Here is my current code:

```
    paypal.Buttons({

    style: {
        shape: 'rect',
        color: 'blue',
        layout: 'vertical',
        label: 'paypal',
        locale: 'en_CY'
    },

    createOrder: function(data, actions) {
        return actions.order.create({
            purchase_units: [{
                amount: {
                    value: ". $row['paypal_price'] .",
                    currency: 'EUR'
                }
            }]
        });
    },
    onApprove: function(data, actions) {
        return actions.order.capture().then(function(details) {
            localStorage.clear();
            window.location.href = 'http://localhost/website/thankyou.php';
            //alert('Transaction completed by ' + details.payer.name.given_name + '!');
            $stock = 0;
        });
    }
}).render('#paypal-button-container');
```

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question is more about "how do i update my current stock" and "how do i get my current stock"

Javascript runs client-side, since you dont have your current stock-number on client-side, you will need to make Javascript communicate with your server.

One way to do this is via ajax. You can use the [fetch-api](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch) to accomplish this.

This is what you have to do:

Before you display the button (php-code):

```
<?php
    // your code ...
    // check stock before you echo. Only echo when $stock is > 0
    
    $stock = /* get current stock-amount */;

    if ($stock > 0) {
        echo "paypal.Buttons([...";
    }
```

Update your stock on confirmed payment:

```
// your current code
localStorage.clear();
window.location.href = 'http://localhost/website/thankyou.php';
// alert('Transaction completed by ' + details.payer.name.given_name + '!');
// $stock = 0;

// add something like this
const formData = new FormData();
formData.append('amountOrdered', /* number as string */);

// maybe use await to block further processing until stock has been updated
fetch('update_stock.php', {
     method: 'POST',
     body: formData
});
```

In your new `update_stock.php`:

```
<?php
    // update your stock-source by reducing it by $_POST['amountOrdered']
```

The last step you will need is to check your stock right before you create an order (JS):

```
// async here needed so you can use await
createOrder: async function(data, actions) {
    // check stock here
    let stock = (await fetch('get_current_stock.php')).json();
    let currentStock = stock['current'];

    // you may want to check for amoutTryingToOrder instead of 1
    if (currentStock < 1) {
        alert('Out of stock, sorry :(');
        return false;
    }

    return actions.order.create({
```

In your `get_current_stock.php`:

```
<?php
    header('Content-Type: application/json');

    $currentStock = /* get current stock */;
    
    echo json_encode([
        'current' => $currentStock
    ]);
```

Comment: Thank you. This was very helpful!

Comment: Hello, I know you have answered my question a while ago but I have a question about your solution. I have used you solution and I've encountered a problem. I have added an UPDATE statement to the update_stock.php page however, when a peyment gets prossessed the stock number changed for all items instead the one being purchased. I have tried many solutions but none have worked. What can I do in order to reduce the stock of the item being ordered. Thanks again!

Comment: Well in your `update_stock.php` you have to send your item id aswell and use this id to reduce the amount. I dont know your code, but in case you update the stock using sql, you have to use the id in your update statement. Eg.: `update items set stock = <new-stock-value> where item_id = <the-item-id>`. If you omit the where all items will get updated (this is what you described). If this doesnt help, create a new question and provide all essential details.

Answer (score 0):

Your createOrder function can return false when it's not in stock, rather than proceeding with the actions.order.create